# Why doesn't My CSS Styling doesn't match up properly?

Tags: html, css

First heads up is that I'm in my first year at University and I *could* be making a dumb as balls mistake. However, when I try to get my `a:selected` to be the same length as my `li:hover`, the a:selected seems to be off by a few amount of pixels. I've been messing with the padding and still have no luck. Is there a specific reason with my CSS used or a technical problem/browser interpreting it differently?

Here's my CSS:

```
a {
  font-family: Armata;
}
body {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/26DXP2k.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: fixed;
}
#siteNavigation {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 55px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
#siteNavigation li:hover {
  padding: 0px 0px;
  background-color: #E03A00;
  border-top: 10px solid #E03A00;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #BDBFBE;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #BDBFBE;
}
#siteNavigation a:hover {
  color: #BDBFBE;
  padding: 10px 45px;
}
#siteNavigation ul {
  margin-top: 0px;
  color: inherit;
}
#siteNavigation li {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  color: #E03A00;
  background-color: #BDBFBE;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #E03A00;
  border-top: 6px solid #BDBFBE;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
#siteNavigation a {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px 45px;
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #E03A00;
}
#siteNavigation #selected a {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px 45px;
  background-color: #E03A00;
  border-top: 10px solid #E03A00;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #BDBFBE;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #BDBFBE;
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title>First Web page</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="author" content="Matthew Sharp" />
        <meta name="description" content="Index page" />
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Armata%7cLobster%7cRoboto%7cPontano+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <!-- Grey Color's {Light to dark}: 
            FCFFFD
            E3E5E4
            BDBFBE
            7E7F7F
            3F403F 
            ORANGE: E03A00 //Comment used for personal use due to non saved kuler -->   
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav id="siteNavigation">
     <ul>
         <li>
             <a href="index.html">Home</a>
         </li>
         <li id="selected">
             <a href="">Structure</a>
         </li>
         <li>
             <a href="commonElements.html">Common Elements</a>
         </li>
         <li>
             <a href="cssSelectors.html">CSS Selectors</a>
         </li>
         <li>
             <a href="commonCss.html">Common CSS</a>
         </li>
     </ul>

</nav>

    <section id="bodyLayer">


    </body>
```

And the results can be seen here:
       [image]

Cheers.

Comment: Why the jquery tag? There's no Javascript here. You should post your HTML as well. Use a Stack Snippet so that the results can be viewed live here.

Comment: I just ran with whatever the site suggested in my tired state. I can see now though why I shouldn't have done so, a flood of people interested in jquery coming to see what's going on.

Comment: you'r css is a mess. You have  a `li:hover` and then `li a:hover`. That's not necessary. You need to rethink the entire logic of the site. You also have 2 definitions for `#selected` and `li a:hover` but they are exatly the same...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wqsf4ocx/ In case anyone wants to have a go at it.  There's a few rules of thumb to keep in mind that can mitigate these kinds of issues in the future.  Try to keep the majority of the styling in lists like this on the `a` tag and not the `li`.  Try to avoid using `display:inline` or `display:inline-block` on horizontal menus.  Those display modes respect whitespace and cause gaps just like this.  Instead use display block and float them.  If you need it centered, use `margin: auto` or if full width `display:table` and company.  Not a solution but good to keep in mind.

Comment: I suggest that you use javascript to achieve what you require. It will make it easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a cleaned up version of your navigation:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rxh17e3h/

Use `float:left` instead of `display:inline-block`

Use `class="selected"` istead of `id`

Control everything from the `li`. Don't assign hover to the `a` tag

```
a {
  font-family: Armata;
}
body {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/26DXP2k.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: fixed;
}
#siteNavigation {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 55px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

#siteNavigation ul {
  margin-top: 0px;
  color: inherit;
}

#siteNavigation li {
float:left;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px 0px;
list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #E03A00;
  border-top: 6px solid transparent;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #BDBFBE;
  color: #E03A00;
}

#siteNavigation li a{
    padding: 10px 45px;
      color:inherit;  
    text-decoration: none;
}

#siteNavigation li:hover, #siteNavigation li.selected{
    color: #BDBFBE;
    background-color: #E03A00;
    border-top: 6px solid #E03A00;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #BDBFBE;
}
```

Comment: Cheers for that, I can see now that I had two behaviours conflicting each other.. (I'd +1 but not enough rep lol)

Comment: No problem mate. You can mark the correct answer once regardless of rep. Check this out too > http://jsfiddle.net/rxh17e3h/1/

Answer (score 1):

Solution in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wqsf4ocx/1/)

Basically, the problem is that you're applying the `selected` CSS to the `a` tag, when you wanted to apply it to the `li` tag.

The `a` tag captures the text and a small area around it based on the margin and padding, but the actual "cell" is represented by the `li` tag, so that's where you want to apply the `selected` CSS.

```
#siteNavigation #selected a { /*should be #siteNavigation li#selected*/
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px 45px;
  background-color: #E03A00;
  border-top: 10px solid #E03A00;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #BDBFBE;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #BDBFBE;
}
```

I also tidied up some of the CSS, like removing the unnecessary padding, the too-thick `border-top` for `selected`, and added this :

```
#siteNavigation #selected a{
  color: #BDBFBE;
}
```

So the text color would be correct.

Check the JSFiddle for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that quite simply you are putting an action on the

tag and expecting it to behave in the same way as the same action on an  tag. Quite simply the two tags hold a different space on your page. The

contains your  tag.

So apply the behaviour to one or the other. 
Some just target the a tag with a:hover a:selected etc others will target li. Whenever I get problems like this I just comment out the dimension code and un comment until the error appears or just use firebug.